# windowmanager doesn't receive clicks with some devices with the same OS version?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, window-managers, huawei-mobile-services

am working in some window manager issue, its like facebook chat head, 
actions can be done with it : 
1.onTouch = i can move it across the screen 
2.there is a close button under that head that suppose t close it : and it working very well. 
3.click the head it self suppose to close it then starts another service in the background.

** the problem is : clicking the head is not working on my phone-huawei mate 10 lite- android 8.0.0 API 26 although its working on the same API on emulator, 
and the same happend with samsung S8+ same android version (note: it was working here before)
and it worked on another huawei with same android version
anyone knows what could be the problem ? 
* overlay permission granted *huawei dropzone not blocking it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i figured out the problem, it was some conflict between the onTouch method that i implemented on the window manager-in order to receive co-ordinates to move the window- and the onClick listener on the main View that was added to the window manager so when i removed the onTouch Listener it worked properly